# vector::push_back and std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue

I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct test{
    test(){}
    test(test const &){
        std::cout<<__LINE__<<"\n";
    }
    test(test&&){
        std::cout<<__LINE__<<"\n";
    }
};

#include <vector>
#include <utility> // std::move
int main(){
    auto&& tmp = test();
    std::vector<test> v;
    v.push_back(tmp);
    std::cout<<__LINE__<<"\n";
    v.push_back(std::move(tmp));

    return 0;
}
```

The vs2013 compiler output:

6 // copy

18

9 // move

9 // move

The g++ and clang++ output:

6 // copy

18

9 // move

6 // copy

My problems are:

1. Is the type of tmp test&&? Is tmp a rvalue?
2. If the type of tmp is test&&, why didn't the first push_back use move constructor?
3. Where did the last output come from? Why did vs2013 and g++ output different results?

Thanks.

Answer for 3rd problem:
It comes from the reallocation as commented by andrew.punnett.

Comment: I've amended my answer to expand Andrew's comment.

Comment: The most efficient solution is `v.emplace_back();` which requires neither copies nor moves.

Comment: Note: `v.emplace_back()` does move the object, if it was constructed before the call

Comment: @DarkWanderer `v.emplace_back();` constructs the object directly inside the vector's memory. There is no object created before the call.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Nope. `MyClass instance; v.emplace_back(instance);`. Although I was wrong about moving, it would be copying via copy-constructor.

Comment: @DarkWanderer You are not supposed to pass an instance to `emplace_back`. Just write `v.emplace_back();` verbatim without anything inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the type of `tmp` `test&&`?

Yes and no. `tmp` is an rvalue reference variable of type `test&&`, but the identifier `tmp` taken as an expression has type `test` and value category *lvalue*. The `&` is never part of the type of an expression.

> Is `tmp` a rvalue?

No. Any use of an identifier is an lvalue expression, even the name of an rvalue reference. Rvalue reference variables are accessed essentially identically to lvalue reference variables; only `decltype(tmp)` can tell the difference. (Often you would use `decltype((tmp))` to *avoid* telling the difference.)

> If the type of tmp is test&&, why didn't the first push_back use move constructor?

Because the name of an rvalue reference is still an lvalue. To get an rvalue expression, use `move(tmp)`.

> Where did the last output come from? Why did vs2013 and g++ output different results?

Clang and GCC only made room for one object in the `vector` by default. When you added the second object, the vector storage was reallocated causing the objects to be copied. Why weren't they moved? Because the move constructor is not `noexcept`, so if it threw an exception, it would be impossible to undo the reallocation.

As for the two moves by MSVC, there are two possibilities, which you can distinguish by experimentation — I don't have a copy handy.

1. MSVC reserved enough space inside the vector for two objects by default. The second move is from an internal local variable.
2. MSVC ignored the requirement that the move constructor be `noexcept` and called it to perform relocation anyway. This would be a bug, but in this case it's covering up a common mistake.

If you replace `vector` with `deque`, you won't see any more copies, because `deque` is not allowed to assume copyability.

Comment: Mostly correct, but the extra calls to the constructor are just because the vector is being relocated not use of a "temporary internal variable". For example try v.reserve(2) just after creation of the vector.

Comment: Isn't there some reference collapsing trickery going on here, i.e. `tmp` is whatever is returned by the RHS? It is the same as the whole "universal references" thing.

Comment: So test&& has no superiority against test&?

Comment: @andrew.punnett Thanks, I just assumed GCC and Clang had reserved sufficient space. (`test` should only be one byte, and there's seldom an advantage to dynamically allocating less than a few words' worth.) Aaand, an MSVC bug looks likely. Typical.

Comment: @user1535111 Depends what you mean by "superiority". The big difference between rvalue references and lvalue references is how they're initialized. Try substituting `auto &` and see what happens.

Comment: @user1535111 It's a different thing. `test&&` can bind to an rvalue, `test&` can't.

Comment: @FredOverflow Not true. `auto &&` in a local declaration is deduced the same as a template parameter.

Comment: @FredOverflow I am pretty sure it could bind to anything. That is the point of using it.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio do not yet support the noexcept keyword and is likely not compliant to the exception safety of push_back. Also, the additional output is a result of the difference on capacity computation on grow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility> // std::move

struct Except{
    Except(){}
    Except(Except const &) {
        std::cout<< "COPY\n";
    }
    Except(Except&&)  {
        std::cout<< "MOVE\n";
    }
};

struct NoExcept{
    NoExcept(){}
    NoExcept(NoExcept const &) noexcept {
        std::cout<< "COPY\n";
    }
    NoExcept(NoExcept&&) noexcept {
        std::cout<< "MOVE\n";
    }
};

template <typename T> void Test( char const *title,int reserve = 0) {
    auto&& tmp = T();
    std::cout<< title <<"\n";
    std::vector<T> v;
    v.reserve(reserve);

    std::cout<< "LVALUE REF ";
    v.push_back(tmp);
    std::cout<< "RVALUE REF ";
    v.push_back(std::move(tmp));
    std::cout<< "---\n\n";
}
int main(){
    Test<Except>( "Except class without reserve" );
    Test<Except>( "Except class with reserve", 10 );
    Test<NoExcept>( "NoExcept class without reserve" );
    Test<NoExcept>( "NoExcept class with reserve", 10 );
}
```

And the result within clang :

```
Except class without reserve
LVALUE REF COPY
RVALUE REF MOVE
COPY
---

Except class with reserve
LVALUE REF COPY
RVALUE REF MOVE
---

NoExcept class without reserve
LVALUE REF COPY
RVALUE REF MOVE
MOVE
---

NoExcept class with reserve
LVALUE REF COPY
RVALUE REF MOVE
---
```